# Preserving line breaks and paragraph ends when pasting to LyX

Tags: lyx, line-breaking

When pasting (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) text in LyX all line endings are removed.
When pasting as special text (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>) all line endings are replace by paragraph ends. I have text that has both paragraphs and line breaks.

**How can it be pasted into Lyx preserving the line breaks** (as distinct from paragraph ends)?

When pasting from the web to LibreOffice Writer it is preserved correctly so I am quite certain that the information is there.

If not possible how can the result be otherwise achieved?

Search and replace in LyX does not seem to be able to search line endings and doing it directly in the LyX file seems like the very last resort, given how chatty the format is...

Comment: Lyx does try to emulate the output through its presentation, where line-breaks are merged. That's the way TeX treats that type of content, so it seems like LyX is doing what it's intended to do. One would have to introduce explicit code to render it differently. You may consider pasting the content in the source rather than the display (if that's possible).

Comment: @Werner There is no problem with rendering (not in this question), but in the text input. LyX apparently distinguishes and correctly presents both paragraph ends and line breaks. My copied text has both, but LyX somehow refuses to accept that... Doing it in the source works, but it also defeats the purpose of LyX in the first place...

Comment: So what you're saying is that when you write on line n: "Something ..." and line n+1: "Something else ..." that when you paste that into LyX is should be displayed on 2 separate lines? Again, text written that way is interpreted as being of the same paragraph by TeX, and LyX's interface is a representation of that, so it makes sense that it's put within the same paragraph (so, line breaks are removed).

Comment: Say we have html like this: <p>Something ...<br>Something else</p><p>third line<br>fourth line</p> that is two paragraphs, each has two lines (one line break). LyX can do both (paragraph (not rendered as character but by indentation) and line break (shown as little red enter symbol)). Question is how to put it in other than manually.

Comment: Or put differently: how should the text look like so that when pasted the desired combination of line break and paragraps is achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LyX aims to maintain the interpretation of TeX in its representation. So, input text representing

```
Line 1
Line 2
```

will be considered as part of the same paragraph and therefore pasted that way:

```
Line 1 Line 2
```

or within the editor as:

[image]

If you want to force these to have a rigid line-break the way you have it in the input text, add the line-break `\\` verbatim

```
Line 1 \\
Line 2
```

and Edit > Paste Special > Paste from LaTeX:

[image]